# segfault on memcpy to uint16_t from socket recv()

Tags: c, sockets, char, memcpy

I'm sending a uint8_t followed by a uint16_t over a C socket, but for some reason I keep getting segfaults when I try to copy the data from the char buffer over.

```
// sending code:
uint8_t a_t = A;
uint16_t b = htons(B);

int len = sizeof(uint8_t) + sizeof(uint16_t); // should be 3 bytes
char buf[3];
memcpy(&buf, &cmd_t, sizeof cmd_t);
size_t offset = sizeof(uint8_t);
memcpy(&buf[offset], &cmd, sizeof cmd); // this works
send(sockfd, buf, len, 0);

// receiving code:

char buf[256];    
int nbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
if (nbytes >0 ){
handleData(buf, nbytes); // buf = "\0\0-100/156"
}



 void handleData(char *buf, int nbytes) {
// buf = "" ????
    uint8_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    memcpy(&a, buf, sizeof(uint8_t));
    memcpy(&b, buf[1], sizeof(uint16_t)); // <-- Segfaults here
    int B = ntohs(b); // convert b to actual number
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `memcpy(&b, buf[1], sizeof(uint16_t));` -->> `memcpy(&b, buf+1, sizeof(uint16_t));` (and: you have to check that `(nbytes >=3)` )

Comment: Or even better: `memcpy(&b, buf+1, sizeof b);` (still need to check nbytes, though ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
memcpy(&b, buf[1], sizeof(uint16_t)); // <-- Segfaults here
```

It is because `buf[1]` is a `char`, and `memcpy` expects a coherent address (and reading from `buf[1]` gives you garbage).
As @joop stated in his comment, you should rather:

```
memcpy(&b, buf+1, sizeof(uint16_t));
```

or:

```
memcpy(&b, &buf[1], sizeof(uint16_t));
```

Here you give to `memcpy` the address of `buf` with an offset of `1`.